# How to perform calculations when the integral of a mixed exponential distribution pdf does not give 1?

Tags: mean, exponential-distribution, median, mixture-distribution, integral

Let Y be the time, for a mixture distribution with two exponential distributions, each multiplied by a and b and having 2 different parameters. How can calculations such as mean, variance and quartiles be performed when integrating the pdf from infinity to 0 does not yield 1? ( considering that y<0 equals 0).

Thanks for your help.

[image: Mixed exponential distribution]

Comment: Well, $b=1-a$ for this to be a pdf of a mixed distribution.

Comment: **Normalize it.**  Because the integral equals $a+b,$ dividing the entire expression by $a+b$ gives a potentially valid pdf.  (To be fully valid, it has to have nonnegative values for all $y\gt 0.$  That can be guaranteed by assuming $a$ and $b$ are both nonnegative.)

Comment: Many many thanks @whuber ,it worked.